# "No Class Def Found Error" appeared after adding a library, but still not fixed after removing it

Tags: android, kotlin, noclassdeffounderror

After adding a video trimmer library this error below appeared on application starts, After removing the library and its dependencies the error still. I tried for hours to solve the problem, and tried to use tips in previous questions, but nothing changed. So, if anyone can help.
Thank you..

> Process: com.example.appName, PID: 16060
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/appcheck/interop/InternalAppCheckTokenProvider;
> at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseRegistrar.getComponents(DatabaseRegistrar.java:41)
> at com.google.firebase.tracing.ComponentMonitor.processRegistrar(ComponentMonitor.java:28)
> at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.discoverComponents(ComponentRuntime.java:117)
> at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.(ComponentRuntime.java:99)
> at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.(ComponentRuntime.java:46)
> at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime$Builder.build(ComponentRuntime.java:387)
> at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.(FirebaseApp.java:438)
> at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:295)
> at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:263)
> at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:248)
> at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(FirebaseInitProvider.java:69)
> at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2421)
> at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2386)
> at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(FirebaseInitProvider.java:61)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7870)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:7381)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7087)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:271)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2134)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8319)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:556)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.appcheck.interop.InternalAppCheckTokenProvider" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.appName/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes13.dex", zip file "/data/app/~~wRT3Ad4JPIY8gFlyY29vFA==/com.example.appName-lARCixeEvl5UvotTHN78aA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~wRT3Ad4JPIY8gFlyY29vFA==/com.example.appName-lARCixeEvl5UvotTHN78aA==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~wRT3Ad4JPIY8gFlyY29vFA==/com.example.appName-lARCixeEvl5UvotTHN78aA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
> at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
> at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseRegistrar.getComponents(DatabaseRegistrar.java:41) 
> at com.google.firebase.tracing.ComponentMonitor.processRegistrar(ComponentMonitor.java:28) 
> at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.discoverComponents(ComponentRuntime.java:117) 
> at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.(ComponentRuntime.java:99) 
> at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.(ComponentRuntime.java:46) 
> at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime$Builder.build(ComponentRuntime.java:387) 
> at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.(FirebaseApp.java:438) 
> at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:295) 
> at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:263) 
> at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:248) 
> at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(FirebaseInitProvider.java:69) 
> at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2421) 
> at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2386) 
> at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(FirebaseInitProvider.java:61) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7870) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:7381) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7087) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:271) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2134) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
> at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8319) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:556) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1038)

build.gradle(:app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
    id 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.appName'
    compileSdk 33

    buildFeatures {
        compose true
        dataBinding true
        viewBinding true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.appName"
        minSdk 31
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerVersion "1.5.10"
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.0-alpha02"
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:1.4.2'
    implementation 'androidx.media2:media2-widget:1.2.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    implementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    implementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'


    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.getstream:stream-chat-android:3.6.3'
    //implementation project(':chat')
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.15.1'
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.3"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.3"
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'



    // Retrofit + GSON
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.1'



    //Kotlin components
    constraints {
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.0") {
            because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
        }
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.0") {
            because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
        }
    }
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.4.2'
    kapt "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.21"
    api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4"
    api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4"





    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.5.0-alpha03"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:1.5.0-alpha03"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:'
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.5.0-alpha03"

    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1'


    /*Hauler*/
    implementation("app.futured.hauler:hauler:5.0.0")
    // optional dependency with set of Data Binding adapters
    implementation("app.futured.hauler:databinding:5.0.0")




    // Firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.3'

    // Import the Firebase BoM
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.5.0')
    // When using the BoM, don't specify versions in Firebase dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
    // Add the dependency for the Firebase Authentication library
    // When using the BoM, you don't specify versions in Firebase library dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:24.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.5.0'  //
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx'
    // Add the dependency for the Performance Monitoring library
    // When using the BoM, you don't specify versions in Firebase library dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1'


    //Image Picker
    implementation 'com.github.dhaval2404:imagepicker:2.1'
    //Circle Image
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    //Timber
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:5.0.1'
    //Fast Scroll
    implementation 'xyz.danoz:recyclerviewfastscroller:0.1.3'
    //Storage Picker
    // ReactiveX
    def rx_version = "3.0.0"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxandroid:$rx_version"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:$rx_version"
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.21'
    implementation "com.anggrayudi:storage:1.5.4"
    //Skydoves
    implementation "com.github.skydoves:landscapist-glide:2.1.11"
    implementation "com.github.skydoves:landscapist-placeholder:2.1.11"
    implementation "com.github.skydoves:retrofit-adapters-result:1.0.6"
    //Simple Search View
    implementation 'com.github.Ferfalk:SimpleSearchView:0.2.0'
    //Fast Scroll
    implementation "io.github.l4digital:fastscroll:2.1.0"
    //Wave
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.3'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.3'
    implementation 'com.github.lincollincol:amplituda:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer:1.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer-dash:1.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.media3:media3-ui:1.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.media3:media3-session:1.0.1'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4"
    //Coil
    implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.3.0")
    implementation("io.coil-kt:coil:2.3.0")
    implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-video:2.3.0")
    //Sky Doves
    implementation "com.github.skydoves:cloudy:0.1.2"
    //Permissions
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-permissions:0.31.1-alpha"



    /*Compose*/
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.4.2"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-util:1.4.2"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.0.1"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.3"
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.1'
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:1.4.2"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.1"
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.4.2"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:1.5.0-alpha03"
    implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.5.0-alpha03"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose:2.6.1"


    /*Hilt*/
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.45"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.45"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0"


    /*Exo Player*/
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.18.6'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.18.6'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:2.18.6'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-hls:2.18.6'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-smoothstreaming:2.18.6'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.18.6'




    /*Cam2*/
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-core:1.3.0-alpha06")
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.3.0-alpha06")
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.3.0-alpha06")
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-extensions:1.3.0-alpha06")
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-view:1.3.0-alpha06")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this dependency and try updating all firebase dependencies.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1'
```

Comment: I tried this, it didn't work for me

Comment: Try using firebase-bom, it will configure compatibilities of all firebase dependencies by itself.

Answer (score 11):

Update to the latest version of firebase-bom

```java
implementation platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.0.0")
```

I had the same error but I updated from firebase-bom:30.3.1 to 32.0.0

Comment: Saved alot of my time..thanks dude..

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to check the laster firebase-bom lib https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#bom_v32-4-21

In my case:

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.4.1')
```